# why geckdriver(in selenium,python) makes google think i am a robot but on normal firefox(with same ip) works just fine

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have a code which scrapes google searches for its URL and headings (for only ads) by first enabling a tor Ip and then begin scraping.

Now, my issue is when on tor Ip the gecko driver redirects my search queries on Google to a "click images to confirm you are not a robot" page but if I use google normally on Firefox(with same tor ip) it works fine.
This goes on with my default IP address as well

Ps. I am using selenium web driver in my python 3.6 code

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To help us help you, please read the guidelines on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve